# read.csv runs halfway, ends up giving warning

Tags: r

I have 3 columns in a csv file, one value under certain column is such that it stops the execution of read.csv halfway by giving warning:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

i tried to disable quoting, also tried sep = ",",
The entry that causes the problem is the first one

```
 Sr   CompanyName   url                      Copyright
  1    The Printery  www.iprintery.com   "/*IE only hack*/
                                             width: 100%;
                                               }

    .                                        dropmenudiv a:hover{ /*THEME CHANGE 
                                             HERE*/
                                             text-decoration: none;
                                             font-weight: normal;
                                             color: ;
                                             background: ;
                                              }
                                              -->
                                             </style>

                                             <script type=""text/javascript"" 
                                             src=""/chromejs/chrome.js"">


                                            </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            <div align=""center"" 
                                            style=""padding-top:10px;"">
 2  Tannen's       tannens149.com         Tannens 149
```

PS:I tried all the related method on stack overflow and none works.

Comment: This doesn't look at all like CSV data, it looks the source code for a webpage.  Why do you want to use `read.csv()` to handle this?

Comment: it's scrape data that is written into a csv file, few entries are such that cause problems. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Pandsh, have you tried `fread` from `data.table` library, it's faster and can handle this fine

Comment: @ParthChaudhary tried already, it gives EOF-non printing character error.

Comment: @Pandsh, did u try `fread` with `fill = TRUE` option ?

Comment: The main problem with fread is because it falls under data.table. So when I run my matching code for two columns (splitting them into words), it would convert a column data to multiple column. can you help here? @ParthChaudhary

Comment: @Pandsh, rather than splitting into words and keeping into single column, i've another alternative 
say `df$Copyright` contains last column, then apply following steps : 
`df$Copyright<- gsub( "[^[:alnum:]]", " ", df$Copyright)` and `df$Copyright<- stripWhitespace(df$Copyright)`...  above steps will clean the **Copyright** column into words, Does this solve the issue ?